# Probability question on random pick

Tags: probability

[image]

Looking at the table, if we pull a business unit's annual profitability at random, and find that they made more than £8,000, what is the probability that it was from 2019?

Would the correct answer be 1/4 if we consider only the TOTAL?

Or how would you calculate it considering the single units, so that we have like 2/4 in 2016, 0 in 2017, 1/4 in 2018, and 3/4 in 2019?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I corrected it, it is actually 'more than 8000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $6$ cells in which the value is more than $8000$. Of these, $3$ of them are in the $2019$ row. Thus, the probability of selecting a cell from $2019$ given its value is more than $8000$ is $\displaystyle\frac{3}{6}=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but shouldn't we include also the other 10 cells in the random pick even if they do not have +8000 ?

Comment: No, because it is already given that the cell has more than $8000$.